# about the pointer array using template in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers

i have a class shown below:

```
template <class TValue>
    class ICData
    {
    private :
TValue value;
    public:
inline ICData()
{
};
TValue get_value();
void set_value(TValue data);
    };

    template <class TValue>
    TValue ICData<TValue>::get_value()
    {
return value;
    }

     template <class TValue>
     void ICData<TValue>::set_value(TValue _value)
     {
value=_value;
     }
```

i know how to make a pointer array by:

```
    ICData <int> *ICArray[10];
    ICArray[0]=new ICData<int>();
    ICArray[1]=new ICData<int>();
```

but is there any way to make a pointer array using template ? like below:

```
            template <class T>// iknow this code is WRONG
    ICData <T> *ICArray[10];
    ICArray[0]=new ICData<int>();
    ICArray[1]=new ICData<float>();
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean a template declaration? Templates are for type redefinitions, but you need to supply the template value at some point.

Comment: i know that i should supply it some where : ICArray[0]=new ICData<int>();

Comment: i wonder how do you intend to use `ICData <T> *ICArray[10];`?

Comment: code updated to show my request more clear .

Comment: @Donotalo look at the difference : ICArray[0]=new ICData<int>();
    ICArray[1]=new ICData<float>();

Comment: Side note: You should really work on your indentation. As it currently stands, it is hard to quickly read and navigate through the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to store a pointer that could point to either a `ICData<int>` or a `ICData<float>` then those types would have to have a common base class and you could use that common base as the type to point to.

As it stands the type `ICData<int>` and `ICData<float>` are not related so other than using `void *` there is no solution to what you want to do that wouldn't involve some ugly casts.

Comment: void *ICArray[10];
  ICArray[0]=new ICData<int>(ln);
  ICArray[1]=new ICData<float>(ln2);
this code works but how can i access ICArray[0].get_Value()?

Comment: @mefmef: You have to cast it back to the correct type first. e.g. `static_cast< ICData<int>& >(ICArray[0]).get_Value()`

Comment: :Error    15    error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'ICData<TValue> &'    c:\documents and settings\h.farazi\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\icarraytest\main.cpp    22    1    ICArrayTest

Comment: @mefmef: Sorry, my mistake, I meant: `static_cast< ICData<int>* >(ICArray[0])->get_Value()`. I'm not sure why you are getting `TValue` in the error message, though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this approach to store both `ICData<int>` and `ICData<float>` in the same `ICArray`.

It could be made to work, if you derive `ICData<T>` from a non-templatized `ICDataBase`, and use `ICDataBase* ICArray[10]`. However, the static type will be lost so most likely (you would want to use the stored value at some point, won't you?) this will lead to a lot of casting.

Another option is to use `boost::any`.

However, usually there is a better approach without using boost::any (although it is justified in some cases). So I would suggest to take a step back and rethink your solution.